# Golang subdirectories

Tags: go

Is there not a way to create a sub-directory for some of my files?  This is purely for file organization.  I've got a large number of small structs/methods that I'd like to put into their own files and into a sub-directory, but I don't want to put them into their own package.  They rely on other functionality in my project.  Each one is anywhere from 10-50 lines and I've been sticking them in one file, but this is ugly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to do it. Go does this on purpose, because if you feel like you need another sub-directory. More than likely you need another package. Also, if you truly do not need a sub-package, then you could just split all those small structs and their appropriate methods into their own separate files in the same package.

Comment: Yuck. I likely have around a hundred.  I'll keep them in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

you could also put them in a separate package and them import all of the in the parent package:

```
  package mainpackage

   import . "mysubpackage" // with all the little sub directory
```

Comment: could I then import the main package from the subdirectory?

Comment: I don't think so because it will be a circular reference